# How to reduce LVM for root partition?

Tags: fedora, lvm, root-filesystem, lvreduce

I am trying to reduce the space dedicated to root LVM since I don't really need it and I am having a few doubts. Below is the output for `lvdisplay`:

```
# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pc_rperez_lvm/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                pc_rperez_lvm
  LV UUID                m7XejM-82cZ-hODn-nT8H-y2BM-3B4s-lq2xgn
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                72.37 GiB
  Current LE             18527
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pc_rperez_lvm/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                pc_rperez_lvm
  LV UUID                Ehl9tF-XV30-uF4Y-T1Bc-WB8r-Pfim-ONQFn3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                25.00 GiB
  Current LE             6400
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pc_rperez_lvm/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                pc_rperez_lvm
  LV UUID                pJuBnV-fhD1-NgOe-xMUc-gck8-CfeM-YkQHAX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

What I want to achieve is shrink `root` to 25gb and then add the free space to `home`. I have read a lot of posts but none of them mention how to achieve this on a root partition with the partition mounted. So having this information, it's possible to reduce the space with partition mounted? If so how? If not what would you recommend me? I am using Fedora 23

What I am missing?

**EDIT: File system:**

As requested this is the file system used:

```
# cat /etc/fsatb
/dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-root /                       ext4
/dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home /home                   ext4
/dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-swap swap                    swap
```

Note: I've read about some Live CD for manage LVM (like GParted) partition but so far I doesn't found any, if you know any add to your reply!!

Articles read: [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/424678/how-to-resize-root-lvm-partition-in-fedora-without-livecd-or-rebooting), [2](http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/09/06/how-to-extend-grow-or-resize-an-lvm-logical-volume/), [3](http://www.linuxtechi.com/reduce-size-lvm-partition/), [4](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/LVM-HOWTO.html) and many others

**EDIT: Can't grow up the other LVM**

I have run the command for shrink the `pc_lvm_root` and everything was fine as show below:

```
$ sudo ssm resize -s 50G /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-root 
fsck from util-linux 2.28
/dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-root: 425214/4743168 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 9042371/18971648 blocks
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-root to 13107200 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-root is now 13107200 (4k) blocks long.

  Size of logical volume pc_rperez_lvm/root changed from 72.37 GiB (18527 extents) to 50.00 GiB (12800 extents).
  Logical volume root successfully resized.
```

Now I want to add those 50G to the `pc_rperez_lvm-home` but I can't, see output below:

```
$ sudo ssm resize -s+50G /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home 
SSM Error (2005): There is not enough space in the pool 'pc_rperez_lvm' to grow volume '/dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home' to size 78538342.4 KB!
```

**EDIT: still can't grow up the LVM**

Sadly I can't grow up the home LVM yet, below is what I did following suggestions from the answer:

```
$ sudo ssm resize /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home 
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home: 34602/1638400 files (3.0% non-contiguous), 2213886/6553600 blocks
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home' first.

SSM Error (2012): ERROR running command: "resize2fs /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home"

$ df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                3.9G  260K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                3.9G  1.4M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1             15G  1.6G   13G  11% /run/initramfs/live
/dev/mapper/live-rw  6.3G  4.2G  2.2G  66% /
tmpfs                3.9G   20K  3.9G   1% /tmp
vartmp               3.9G   63M  3.9G   2% /var/tmp
tmpfs                798M   24K  798M   1% /run/user/1000

$ sudo lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pc_rperez_lvm/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                pc_rperez_lvm
  LV UUID                m7XejM-82cZ-hODn-nT8H-y2BM-3B4s-lq2xgn
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pc_rperez_lvm/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                pc_rperez_lvm
  LV UUID                Ehl9tF-XV30-uF4Y-T1Bc-WB8r-Pfim-ONQFn3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                25.00 GiB
  Current LE             6400
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/pc_rperez_lvm/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                pc_rperez_lvm
  LV UUID                pJuBnV-fhD1-NgOe-xMUc-gck8-CfeM-YkQHAX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts

Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home: 34602/1638400 files (3.0% non-contiguous), 2213886/6553600 blocks
```

Ideas at this point?

**EDIT: required information**

```
$ sudo vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               pc_rperez_lvm
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               105.38 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              26976
  Alloc PE / Size       21248 / 83.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       5728 / 22.38 GiB
  VG UUID               Gi0r0L-gRJe-Tzwz-QQE0-CLOY-ofb2-Hk5YCe

$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home 
dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /home
Filesystem UUID:          eb319b45-03f2-49d3-b849-6e1ff4b19046
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1638400
Block count:              6553600
Reserved block count:     327680
Free blocks:              4358401
Free inodes:              1607559
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1022
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Fri Mar 18 13:16:13 2016
Last mount time:          Thu Jul  7 08:06:05 2016
Last write time:          Thu Jul  7 13:21:17 2016
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Jul  7 07:56:48 2016
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          714 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      a4d5967b-3ad8-4d22-833d-a6126de8ee41
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journal size:             128M
Journal length:           32768
Journal sequence:         0x002cb467
Journal start:            0
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add what filesystem you are using for / to your question? The quickest way to find this is probably `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @JasonAzze added to the OP ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resize2fs` does not support shrinking of a mounted file system:

> DESCRIPTION
>          The resize2fs program will resize ext2, ext3, or ext4 file systems.  It can be used to enlarge or shrink an unmounted file system
>   located on device.  If the
>          filesystem is mounted, it can be used to expand the size of the mounted filesystem, assuming the kernel and  the  file  system 
>   supports  on-line  resizing.

As you are using fedora distribution, it's much easier to use `System Storage Manager` to change the size of your file system as it takes care on underlying partition/logical volume size change in one shot. Though you would need to boot the system off the one of [LiveCD spins](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/), provided by Fedora community (I recommend XFCE or LXDE to reduce the download size a bit), so in the terminal window just issue:

```
sudo ssm resize -s -5G /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-root
```

to decrease the root fs by 5 gigabytes, or

```
sudo ssm resize -s 15G /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-root
```

To set the fs size to 15 gigabytes.

If the `ssm` is not available in the live CD you would download, then do

```
sudo yum install system-storage-manager
```

prior to re-sizing.

to extend a volume to the maximum available space just omit the `-s` option:

```
sudo ssm resize /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home
```

Comment: Can you take a look to my second edit and improve your answer adding that?

Comment: I believe it's due to the actual free space in the volume group a bit less than 50G. see the update, please

Comment: I can't grow up the LVM see the latest edit on the OP, any other advice?

Comment: what `vgdisplay` shows and what `dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm-home` shows?

Comment: I've added the information to  the OP ...

Comment: Strange... it should work. Does `pvdisplay` show 'yes' for 'Allocateable'?

Comment: yes, it shows as `Allocatable: yes` is there any other way to achieve the same? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Then try the other answer: it shows the decomposition of what `ssm resize` does

Comment: I've tried the following, close session on terminal1(`tty1`), changed to a new terminal (`tty2`) and login as root, try to unmount `/home` and I get the following message `unable to mount /home target is busy` do I need to run the command from the live CD as well?

Comment: You need not to unmount /home as you are going to expand it and it is possible with online mounted fs

Comment: I keep reading and reading, almost every post I've found says I need to unmount the partition I want to resize since resize2fs doesn't support online resizing on Etx4 parition. I've tried also Gparted but this one doesn't even see the LVM, any other advice?

Comment: Really? I have ext4 on root partition and I have no problems to expand it online. I am running 3.19.8 kernel, quite mature atm. (the latest update from FC20)

Comment: take a look to the comment I leave in the other post, also I am running `4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64` probably latest for FC24

Comment: BTW, does `gparted` (the GUI version of `parted`) allow you to expand the /home online?

Comment: No, take a look to the attached pic, that `/dev/sda6/` is all I can see and is the whole PV

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know before you do anything take a full backup if you can or at least your root drive. Messing with LVM is all good until there is a mistake then its hard to get stuff back.

Now you will want to do this on a live CD as the root partition needs to be unmounted and then from a terminal in the live session we will do the following.

**Make sure that the root LVM is unmounted**

The `mount` should only show mountpoints related to the live CD

```
# mount
```

**Check the root filesystem for errors**

```
# e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm/root
```

**Shrink the root filesystem**

We always want a little buffer room to be safe when shrinking

```
# resize2fs /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm/root 23500M
```

**Shrink the root LV**

```
# lvresize -L 24G pc_rperez_lvm/root
```

**Check the root LV**

You should now see that you have 'Free PE' and you root filesystem is ~24G

```
# vgdisplay
# lvdisplay pc_rperez_lvm/root
```

**Expand the root filesystem to fill the LV**

Don't want to waste that space.

```
# resize2fs -M /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm/root
```

**Assign extents to home LV**

```
# lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm/home
```

**Expand home filesystem**

```
# resize2fs -M /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm/home
```

**Reboot**

```
# reboot
```

Comment: Hi there, I am getting this error `# resize2fs -M /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm/home resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/pc_rperez_lvm/home is mounted on /home; on-line resizing required
resize2fs: On-line shrinking not supported` can you give me some adice?

Comment: *advice (typo on the word)

Comment: You need to make sure the volume is unmounted. your cannot shrink a live root volume.